# input with completion in times of lua (nvim-cmp ?)

Tags: autocompletion, lua, plugin-nvim-cmp

```
let user_dir = input('Enter a directory: ', '', 'dir')
```

This is simple not working for me. When I press `<tab>` instead of completion,  I get `^I` .

I use nvim-cmp. Could it be the reason? Can I use nvim-cmp capabilities to get my input completed?

Configuration(a bit TMI) :

```
cmp.setup({
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
    --['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
    --['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
["<Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
      if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_next_item()
      elseif vim.fn["UltiSnips#CanExpandSnippet"]() == 1 then
        feedkey("<Plug>(ultisnips_expand)", "")
      elseif has_words_before() then
        cmp.complete()
      else
        fallback() -- The fallback function sends a already mapped key. In this case, it's probably `<Tab>`.
      end
    end, { "i", "s" }),

    ["<S-Tab>"] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
     if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_prev_item()
      elseif has_words_before() then
        cmp.complete()
      else
        fallback() -- The fallback function sends a already mapped key. In this case, it's probably `<Tab>`.
     end
    end, { "i", "s" }),
    ['<esc>'] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
    if cmp.visible() then cmp.abort()
    else vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("<esc>", true, true, true), "n", true)
    end 
    
end ),
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), -- Accept currently selected item. Set `select` to `false` to only confirm explicitly selected items.
  }),
  sources = cmp.config.sources(
{
    { name = 'buffer', priority = 1 },
    { name = 'path' , proiority=5 },
    { name = 'nvim_lsp', priority =200 }
     

})

})
-- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
  sources = cmp.config.sources({
    { name = 'path' }
  }, {
    { name = 'cmdline' }
  })
})
```

Comment: “Could it be the reason”—does this work if you disable that plugin?

Comment: Test using `nvim --clean` and verify if it works in a clean version?

Comment: Yes, it does work in clean version.

Comment: It works without cmp.

Comment: then you should create a ticket in `cmp` github page

Comment: I did. But maybe there is a creative idea to use cmp completion or to temporary restore completion function to solve it. Or just an entirely different input function.